# Table cell with space appears squashed

Tags: php, dompdf

Edit: I am using domPDF 0.5.1, hosted http://code.google.com/p/dompdf/

I am using HTML table to generate boxes inside which I place one character each, eg. the following table contains the name "kinjal dixit"

```
<table>
<tr>
<td>k</td><td>i</td><td>n</td><td>j</td><td>a</td><td>l</td>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
<td>d</td><td>i</td><td>x</td><td>i</td><td>t</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

there is a style rule like the following:

```
table tr td {
  border: 1px solid black;
  height: 2em;
  width: 2em;
  font-family: monospace;
}
```

When viewing this in a browser, the cell with the space appears the same size as the other cells, but when generating a pdf, the cell with the space appears 'squashed'.

Does anyone have a solution to this?

Edit: in the style, addition to em, i have tried pt and px. In all cases, when viewed in the browser it appears okay, but when converted to pdf, it does the same thing.

Edit: The dompdf library uses something called "R&OS CPDF" class by default.  There is a way to configure PDFLib. I am reading on that.

Comment: What are you using to generate the PDF?

Comment: Based on the tag, and Google, this: http://www.digitaljunkies.ca/dompdf/

Comment: If you use px or pt sizes for your width height does it work better?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved (=hacked?)

changed:

```
<td>&nbsp;</td>
```

to:

```
<td>&nbsp; &nbsp;</td>
```

(there is a space between the two nbsp)

and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `&nbsp;` instead of just leaving the cell empty.

Answer (score 0):

DOMPDF 0.5.1 strips non-breaking spaces from text. The 0.6.0 release (currently in beta) addresses this issue.

Compare this render from [0.5.1](http://eclecticgeek.com/dompdf/index.php?input_file=so3642505.htm&dompdf_ver=0.5.1) with this one from [0.6.0 beta 1](http://eclecticgeek.com/dompdf/index.php?input_file=so3642505.htm&dompdf_ver=0.6.0_beta1)